# How to add border for an image?

Tags: graphics, framed, includegraphics, border

I use `\includegraphics` command to insert image to the document. But how can I add a border around this image w/o any margin between border lines and image?
It seems to be very easy, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133450/138900

Answer (score 198, accepted):

I've found that `\frame{\includegraphics{image}}` command works for my case.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that `\frame` existed. I now figured out that `beamer` which defines its own `\frame` macro and `frame` environment also supports the normal `\frame` inside them (be saving and then restoring the default definition locally).

Comment: Note that `\frame` will cause the final box to have no depth, which is fine for image but mostly not for text. `{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{..}}` however will keep the original depth, so that letters like 'y' and 'g' are not moved up.

Comment: I found this to be problematic in Adobe. As you zoom in/out some sides of the box will dissapear

Comment: How to set the Thickness on this?

Answer (score 325):

You can add a frame around it by placing it inside a `\fbox{...}` command.

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[options]{image}}
```

The distance can be set by changing the `\fboxsep` length and the line width with the `\fboxrule` length, e.g. to draw a tight 1pt thick rule around the image use:

```
{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\fbox{\includegraphics[options]{image}}%
}%
```

Using a recent version of my `adjustbox` package you can use:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
% ...
\includegraphics[<your options>,frame]{image}% tight frame
% or 
\includegraphics[<your options>,fbox]{image}% Like normal \fbox
```

There is also `cframe` and `cfbox` for colored frames. All of these allow for multiple optional values, e.g. `frame=<rule width>`. See the manual for more information.

Comment: Thanks, `\frame` works better for me, because I don't need any margin between image and line.

Comment: I now programmed a `frame` option for `\includegraphics`. It will be released with the next package update of `adjustbox`.

Comment: Pleasen i ask if it's possible to have rounded border corners? and how ? thank you.

Comment: @researcher: For rounded corners you need to use TikZ or PS-Tricks. See also [How to draw frame with rounded corners around box](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34088/2975).

Comment: Thanks! the `frame` option of `adjustbox` works very well!

Comment: @MartinScharrer can we use `\setkeys{Gin}{frame}` ? It doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe it should not be `Gin` ? I mean, I get no warning or error, just that other `Gin` options such as `width` no longer work (and no frame is shown)

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă: Using `Gin` after loading `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` should be ok.  I would need to see you exact use case. Feel free to post a follow-up question with your MWE.

Answer (score 76):

You need more fancy frame? The settings that you can adjust:

```
\fboxsep=10mm%padding thickness
\fboxrule=4pt%border thickness
```

and

```
%\fcolorbox{bordercolor}{paddingcolor}{image}
\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{foobarbaz}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\fboxsep=10mm%padding thickness
\fboxrule=4pt%border thickness

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
%\fcolorbox{bordercolor}{paddingcolor}{image}
\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{foobarbaz}}
\caption{This is a black box for demo purpose.}
\label{fig:foobarbaz}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for such complete example, it will help me with my next experiments.

Answer (score 27):

A `tcbox` (or a `tcolorbox`) were missing in this list. Some simple examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \tcbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{frog}}
    
    \tcbox[colframe=green!30!black,
           colback=green!30]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{frog}}
    
    \tcbox[sharp corners, boxsep=5mm, boxrule=1mm, 
            colframe=green!30!black, colback=white]
            {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{frog}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

An alternative to `tcbox` is `tcbincludegraphics` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \tcbincludegraphics[width=5cm]{frog}

    \tcbincludegraphics[colframe=green!30!black,
           colback=green!30, graphics options={height=2cm}, width=.25\linewidth]{frog}

    \tcbincludegraphics[hbox, size=fbox, graphics options={width=3cm}, sharp corners, colframe=red]{frog}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although this is the hardest solution, it is much better than the top rate solution by @theBug

Comment: I wanted no margins, so `\tcbox[size=tight]{}` was a great solution.

Answer (score 9):

Somebody tell me if I've missed an answer already covering this, but my favourite way to do this is using `efbox` and this is my go-to image-framer for simple framing.

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{efbox,graphicx}
\efboxsetup{linecolor=green,linewidth=10pt}
\begin{document}
  \efbox{\includegraphics{cath-gadael-chartref}}
\end{document}
```

[image: cath sy'n gadael ei chartref]

[Disclaimer: code for the image is somewhere on this site, but it's mine so I don't feel obligated to find it.]

Comment: Any cat seeing this must give +1.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Beats `example-image-a`. I think the `mwe` package needs more cats!

Comment: How about [example-image-meow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVHRQ.png)?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `example-image-purr`, `example-image-silent-glare`, `example-image-hiss`, `example-image-growl`, `example-image-prowl` ...?

Comment: I think you got the point. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `example-image-duck`?

Comment: @Skillmon Can ducks purr? No? See. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Bet our resident duck can.

Answer (score 6):

For someone who wants to achieve a similar affect in ConTeXt, 
`\externalfigure` accepts all the options of `\framed`, so one can draw a border using:

```
\externalfigure[file][frame=on]
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this command.

```
 \usepackage{graphicx} 

 \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.005pt}
 \newcommand{\tmpframe}[1]{\fbox{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\tmpframe}[1]{#1}
```

use example:

```
  \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \tmpframe{\includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{images/pathToImage.png}}
      \caption{Some caption text).}  
      \label{fig:myRef}
  \end{figure}
```

If you want to print a picture without a frame, use renewcomand in comment.