# Figures with borders problem

Tags: floats, framed

I am writing my thesis in TexniCenter and I have the following problem. 
I want all my figures to have a border. So I use :

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

in the beginning.

However, every figure after that has a border with width equal to text width, even it is much smaller. For example I use the following code to include an image:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics [width=0.5\textwidth] {myfigure.png}
  \caption[myfigure]%
  {myfigure}
  \label{myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

I want to have a figure with width half the text width. The border though remains full width size. Could you help me please.

Comment: The following question might be of help: [How to add border for an image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20640/2693)

Comment: You mention that *every* figure after `\restylefloat{figure}` has a border of width equal to text width. Do you want *every* figure to have a border of width `0.5\textwidth` instead? Or just *some* of your figures?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the [floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and its `\ffigbox` command with the optional argument `\FBwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=boxed} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\rule{5cm}{1cm}% placeholder for image
}{%
\caption{A figure}%
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
\rule{3cm}{1cm}% placeholder for image
}{%
\caption{A figure}%
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{1cm}% placeholder for image
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Boxed figures]

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \rule{0.5\linewidth}{0pt}\vspace{-10pt}\\
    \includegraphics{figure} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```