# Border or frame around figure

Tags: floats, framed

I'd like to place a border / frame around my figure.

The figure is a bunch of equations:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \[ eqn 1 \]

    \[ eqn 2 \]

    \[ eqn 3 \]

    \caption{\label{myfig} My caption.}
\end{figure}
```

I've tried putting an `\fbox{...}` and `\framebox[\textwidth]{...}` around the equations but it doesn't work.

Preferably, I'd like the border to *not* include the caption.

Any hints are welcome...

---

Related question (though it concerns `\includegraphics` instead):

- [How to add border for an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/how-to-add-border-for-an-image)

Comment: it seems there's no [figure] tag. any reason why? if not, could someone with 300+ perhaps "invent it" by adding it to this question?

Comment: There's a [tag:floats] tag which is for questions about `figure` and `table` environments, which are very similar. I added it to your question.  [tag:figures] is an alias tag which maps to [tag:floats].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the package `mdframed` or `framed` this is possible

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{mdframed}
    \[ eqn 1 \]

    \[ eqn 2 \]

    \[ eqn 3 \]
\end{mdframed}
    \caption{\label{myfig} My caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the difference between `framed` and `mdframed`?

Comment: @aioobe `mdframed` has more options and has, in my opinion, a more user friendly interface for customising it. (`mdframed` frames can also break nicely across pages, but since you're using it in a float, this doesn't matter)

Comment: Hmmmm... When I try this (now, 2.5 years after you answered), I get a partial frame (around only the right and bottom) and not a complete frame.

Comment: Same here, @Shay

Answer (score 7):

Using memoir (a package for books), you can use the

```
\begin{framed}
[...]
\end{framed}
```

construct.  See manual pages 181-183.

Answer (score 6):

IF you don't want to use the `memoir` documentclass, as is suggested in @Sardathrion's answer, you could use the `float` package and, in particular, its `\floatstyle{boxed}` and `\restylefloat` commands.

A nice feature of the `float` package is that it provides the `H` location specifier, as in "I really want this float HERE and nowhere else". Two idiosyncracies of the "boxed" float style are (i) the width of the boxes is that of `\textwidth` (plus a small fudge factor, so that an object of full `\textwidth` width fill fit) and (ii) captions of table and figure floats will always be placed *below* the respective objects. (To change this behavior, one will have to delve into the innards of the code of the `float` package.)

Aside: if you set tables with the "boxed" float style, you'll definitely want to use as few `\hline` commands as possible (or, even better, none at all).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,lipsum}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
ABCDEFG
\caption{A very simple figure}
\end{figure}

\bigskip
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{An equally simple table}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}rlrlr@{}}
Here & There & Here & There & Here & There 
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`tcolorbox` is another alternative for boxing any kind of contents, even equations.

Following code shows two example, both produce floating objects, the first shows the box around the equation but with an independent caption and the second includes the caption as a title for the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{float=htb,
title={#2},#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\[ \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\]

\[ 1 + \frac{1}{\tan^2x}=\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\]
\end{tcolorbox}
\caption{Some title for these equations}
\end{figure}

\begin{myfigure}{Some title for these equations}
\[ \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\]

\[ 1 + \frac{1}{\tan^2x}=\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\]
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]