# Background color boxes around complete figure in LaTeX

Tags: floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rounded corner colored box around figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/rounded-corner-colored-box-around-figure)
>   [Make all figures and tables framed by default?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32457/make-all-figures-and-tables-framed-by-default)

I'd like to make colored boxes (a light graytone) around my figures including the figure description in order to better enhance it from regular text.

Unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to accomplish this. Maybe someone can help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from StackOverflow. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: @JosephWright: I know but this was my first hit.

Comment: @JosephWright: I posted an answer in the meantime because Macro's link didn't really look like a full duplicate to me. Should this one be closed, please merge with question 31545.

Comment: Alternatively, it is possible to convert your image before including into your latex :
`convert img.png -background "#xxxxxx" -alpha remove newimg.png`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a minimal example, for reference, by virtue of [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) and [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) (for colour shades):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx (don't use 'demo' in your document)
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{floatrow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow
\DeclareColorBox{shaded}{\colorbox{black!15}}% Shade is 15% black
\floatsetup{framestyle=colorbox,colorframeset=shaded,framefit=yes,heightadjust=all,framearound=all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{image}
  \caption{This is a caption.}
  \label{fig:myfig1}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:myfig1}.
\end{document}​
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for figures. Does this also work for tables? And more importantly, for floating algorithm package? A quick test does not seem so... Also the documentation of floatrow states that there are some problems with the algorithm package...

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package/environment to draw a gray background and a frame around it. Either add an `adjustbox` environment to every `figure` or define your own environment as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% 'demo' in order to not require actual files to compile this example

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth-2\fboxrule,bgcolor=gray,frame}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=5cm]{file}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth-4pt,margin=0pt 5pt,bgcolor=gray,frame=2pt}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=5cm]{file}
    \caption{Again with some vertical margin and thicker frame}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}


% This should actually go to the preamble:
\newenvironment{myfigure}[1][tbhp]{%
    \begin{figure}[#1]%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth-4pt,margin=0pt 5pt,bgcolor=gray,frame=2pt}
        \centering
}{%
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{figure}
}
%%

\begin{myfigure}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=5cm]{file}
    \caption{You can also define your own environment}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

See the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) manual for all further usable keys. I can get a colored frame using `cframe=<color>`.

[image: Result]