# How do I put a box around the figure and caption both

Tags: floats, border

### Background

There are several questions asking how to put a box around an image, such as [question 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26269/border-or-frame-around-figure), [question 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/how-to-add-border-for-an-image) and [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194321/creating-a-box-around-a-figure-that-includes-the-tabbing-environment).

### Question

How to create a box that includes the image and the caption both. Something like as shown below:

```
\begin{yyyyyyyyyyyy}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{xxxxxxxxx}
\caption[xxxxxxxxxxxxx]{xxxxxx}
\label{fig:base-case-constant-circulation}
\end{figure}
\end{yyyyyyyyyyyy}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `framed` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{framed}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption[xxxxxxxxxxxxx]{xxxxxx}
    \label{fig:base-case-constant-circulation}
  \end{framed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. How can I change the liewidth of this frame?

Comment: To change the width of the framing rule, you can use `\setlength{\FrameRule}{<width>}` with a value of your choice. Pleace thic ocmmand in the preamble to influecne all `framed` environments in the document. Place it inside `figure` but before `framed` to only change this specific frame.