# Add a border to textblock

Tags: color

I'm pretty new to latex, and what I am trying to create a simple [treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping), by simple I mean *really* simple.

I have managed to produce a simple box at a given position and width, but I'm not too sure how to create a border around the textblock.

```
\begin{textblock}{200}(400,200)
  \centering
  \textblockcolour{red}
  \vspace{20mm}
    { \bfseries \Large Hello World }
  \vspace{20mm}
\end{textblock}
```

My Example usage is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
  \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
  \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\usepackage{color}


\begin{document}

  \begin{textblock}{200}(400,200)
    \centering
    \textblockcolour{red}
    \vspace{20mm}
      { \bfseries \Large Hello World }
    \vspace{20mm}
  \end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The textblock documentation suggests doing this using tcolorbox, and gives a link to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34088/how-to-draw-frame-with-rounded-corners-around-box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `showboxes` package option (in the example below I changed the settings for the `textblock` since the original settings place the block outside the page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{200}(0,200)
  \centering
  \textblockcolour{red}
  \vspace{20mm}
    { \bfseries \Large Hello World }
  \vspace{20mm}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, to draw your treemap I would suggest you to use [`PGF/TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) instead.

Here's a simple possibility, using TikZ, to draw a treemap:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{green1}{RGB}{221,242,151}
\definecolor{green2}{RGB}{161,221,135}
\definecolor{purple1}{RGB}{149,87,164}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{42,144,158}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[draw=black,fill=green1] 
  (0,0) rectangle (3.5,-6);
\draw[draw=black,fill=purple1] 
  (3.5,0) rectangle (6,-6);
\draw[draw=black,fill=green2] 
  (0,-6) rectangle (3.8,-9);
\draw[draw=black,fill=blue1] 
  (3.8,-6) rectangle (6,-8);
\draw[draw=black,fill=purple1] 
  (3.8,-8) rectangle (6,-9);

\node at (1.75,-3) {Paul};
\node at (4.75,-3) {Dennis};
\node at (1.9,-7.5) {Rick};
\node at (4.9,-7) {Simon};
\node at (4.9,-8.5) {Alvin};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! I did look at the PGF/Tikz package, but I found it quite hard to understand (being a new latex user). I did manage to find an example to produce something similar
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \draw (0,0) node [fill=red]
  {Text at \verb!node 1!};
\end{tikzpicture}
However I can't seem to position it where I want (I'm using a mm grid). I also couldn't work out how to add padding to the text.

Comment: @clangers I updated my answer showing a possibility using TikZ.

Comment: @clangers give me some minutes and I'll add a more intuitive TikZ-based solution.

Comment: @clangers I updated my answer with a simpler TikZ-based solution.

Comment: thanks for this, it is exactly what I was originally trying to produce. A quick question though, I noticed that your example uses pt for positioning (and sizes?). How can I use mm instead, as I currently have a mm grid on my document. So for example \draw[draw=black,fill=green1] (40mm,100mm) rectangle (60mm,50mm) doesn't seem to place the top-left of the square at 40x100.

Comment: @clangers Since I didn't specify the unit, my code uses centimeters (the default unit in TikZ); of course you can use millimeters instead. Here's a simple example with a grid:

Comment: @clangers `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{green1}{RGB}{221,242,151}
\definecolor{green2}{RGB}{161,221,135}
\definecolor{purple1}{RGB}{149,87,164}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{42,144,158}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1mm,ultra thin,gray!20] (-5,-5) grid (7,10);
\draw[step=1cm,ultra thin,gray!70] (-5,-5) grid (7,10);
\foreach \x in {-5,...,7}
  \node[label = above:$\x$] at (\x,10) {};
\foreach \y in {-5,...,10}
  \node[label = right:$\y$] at (7,\y) {};
\draw[draw=black,fill=green1] (40mm,100mm) rectangle (60mm,50mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`