# How to reduce the left margin of the Friggeri CV template?

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I'd like to reduce the left margin of the Friggeri template, in order to increase the width of the aside section.

I first tried to change the numbers of the line 308 of friggeri-cv.cls file:

```
\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
```

But it was unsuccessful: only the main column moved. After that I found an interesting code in line 163 (aside section).

```
\begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
```

But when I changed those numbers, the aside section changed but the left margin was not reduced.

Maybe I found the right line to change but I don't do it properly? How can I reduce the left margin so that the separation between the aside section and the main section doesn't move, thus increasing the width of the aside section?

[Link to the template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} 

\begin{document}

\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst}

\begin{aside}
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 12345
Country
~
\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\section{languages}
english mother tongue
spanish \& italian fluency
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
Python, C++, PHP
CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

\section{education}
\begin{entrylist}
\entry
{2011--2012}
{Masters {\normalfont of Commerce}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?} \\ This thesis blah blah blah}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output (the arrow represents the margin I'd like to reduce):
[image: the margin i'd like to reduce]

Comment: Please construct a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}`.

Comment: edited to add a MWE and the output

Comment: As I said, I tried this, but only the main column (the one containing "education") moved. Should I include the cls file in the question ?

Comment: Nope, but you should add a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move the aside section by changing the numbers in the textblock command

```
\begin{textblock}{h-width}(x-pos, y-pos)
```

Changing these numbers can be difficult, so I suggest you to add a red background (as shown in this question [Add a border to textblock](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86760/add-a-border-to-textblock)) to better understand what you do.

In this MWE the left margin is reduced:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% copied form line 163 in friggeri-cv
% Side block %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\renewenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(0.5, 4.33)
  \textblockcolour{red}    % this line is here to help you and then should be removed
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}
\begin{document}
\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst}

\begin{aside}
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 12345
Country
~
\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\section{languages}
english mother tongue
spanish \& italian fluency
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
Python, C++, PHP
CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

\section{education}
\begin{entrylist}
\entry
{2011--2012}
{Masters {\normalfont of Commerce}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?} \\ This thesis blah blah blah}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this and come back to tell you how it worked :)

Comment: Hello. So I tried different things. I had to learn how to really use the textblock package (how to set the unit you give the measure in etc...) and it is indeed this line that has to be changed. Thank you very much. Note that I had to redefine the geometry numbers to fit the reduced margin

Answer (score 1):

If you change two lines in your friggeri class file:

`\begin{flushright}` --> `\begin{flushleft}`
`\end{flushright}` --> `\end{flushleft}`

then it looks more accurate for me. You can try this, maybe then you don't have to change the margin.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think this will not work for the OP, because it changes the arrangement of the items on the page. The right-alignment is, in my opinion, a design feature of the template. Thanks for your answer though!