# Making fancy frames around a textblock

Tags: pdftex, textpos

I'm aware of [the question and of the replies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86760/add-a-border-to-textblock)  about borders around a `textblock`  from the `textpos` package. This works but produces "very square" boxes...

I was wondering if there was a way to make those boxes more fancy with, for example with round borders, non rectangular shape (I was thinking about cartoon bubbles), or to add a title, itself in a fancy box, in one step.

I tried to play with `tikz` but I didn't manage to have a common  coordinate system for the `tikz` and for the `textpos` and, moreover, as the height of the `textblock` is variable, I'm not sure to be able to draw the border properly around the `textblock`.

Comment: Packages `mdframed` and `tcolorbox`, very easy to use, the second one being my personal favorite, both highly configurable and with breaking-box-feature (both use `TikZ` in the background, actually)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP's question leaves wide latitude, so I opted to make a fancy frame using those clipart frame corners you can find on the web.  Once you have downloaded such a frame, which I called `corner_299-282.png`, use my macro

```
\cframe{<frame-image-file>}{<offset-factor>}{<content>}
```

One additional parameter is `\frameprop`, which is the proportion of the content's width/height minimum to make the frame.

Here is the MWE.  During the early part of the page, `\frameprop` is set to `.45` (i.e., 45%).  The first row shows the raw frame.  The second row shows it applied to square content, but changing the offset-factor from `0` to `.2`.  The 3rd row shows it applied to rectangular content, also varying the offset-factor.  The last row shows it applied to a text `\parbox`, with the offset at `.35` and `\frameprop` revised to `.6` (60%).

EDITED to allow `<content>` to contain multi-paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\newlength\framewidth
\def\frameprop{.45}
\newcommand\cframe[3]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#3}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax\relax%
  \setlength\framewidth{\frameprop\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}\else%
  \setlength\framewidth{\frameprop\wd0}\fi%
  \savestack\corner{\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{#1}}%
  \hspace{#2\framewidth}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#3}%
  \stackinset{l}{-#2\framewidth}{t}{}{\corner}{%
  \stackinset{r}{-#2\framewidth}{t}{-#2\framewidth}{\rotatebox{-90}{\corner}}{%
  \stackinset{l}{-#2\framewidth}{b}{}{\rotatebox{90}{\corner}}{%
  \stackinset{r}{-#2\framewidth}{b}{-#2\framewidth}{\rotatebox{180}{\corner}}{%
  \copy0}}}}%
  \hspace{#2\framewidth}%
}
\parskip1ex
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=1in]{corner_299-282}\par
\cframe{corner_299-282}{0}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image}}
\quad
\cframe{corner_299-282}{.2}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image}}\par
\cframe{corner_299-282}{0}{\includegraphics[width=2in,height=1in]{example-image}}
\quad
\cframe{corner_299-282}{.2}{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=2in]{example-image}}\par
\def\frameprop{.6}
\cframe{corner_299-282}{.35}{\parbox{2.4in}{
{\centering\scshape A LIMERICK\par}
The lemmings get set for their race.\\
With one step and two steps they pace.\\
\mbox{\quad}They take three and four,\\
\mbox{\quad}And then head on for more, \\
Without checking the limiting case.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Frame source: https://clipartfest.com/download/ANd9GcQdC6b9yPnapPFI-eBCKms0V65w7f9k4VOELXG0JSNKUetQmU2pzq-cFLQ.html

Limerick source: https://www.physics.harvard.edu/academics/undergrad/limericks

Note: `\cframe`s can be nested:

[image]