# Frame option in includegraphics makes an overfull \hbox

Tags: boxes, warnings, adjustbox

I'm using the [adjust](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox) package to add the `frame` option in `\includegraphics` command. The package is loaded in this way:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

Now I can write the following command:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, frame]{foo.png}
```

and borders will be automagically added to the image.

Unfortunately using this options I get the well-known `overfull \hbox (.. too wide) in paragraph` warning. Without the `frame` option the warning disappears.

Does exixst a way to defeat this warning using the `frame` option?

Comment: Is the width of your image set to `\textwidth` or `\linewidth`? The width of the frame comes in addition to that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's set to `\textwidth`

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20640/138900

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how you can do; which one to choose between the second and third example is a matter of taste and of what your pictures contain.

The `frame` option draws a frame with rule of width `\fboxrule` (by default) and zero space between the frame and the box. But the rule width is added to the width of the box, so you have to do something about it: either reduce a bit the width of the box, or draw the frame inside the box, by specifying a negative separation (second parameter to the `frame` option).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\footnotesize

% first example: bad, there's an overfull of twice the rule width    
\verb|\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,frame]{tiger}|\\
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,frame]{tiger}
\end{minipage}

\medskip

% second example: good, the frame is drawn outside the picture
\verb|\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule,frame={\fboxrule}]{tiger}|\\
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth-2\fboxrule,frame={\fboxrule}]{tiger}
\end{minipage}

\medskip

% third example: good, the frame is drawn inside the picture
\verb|\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,frame={\fboxrule} {-\fboxrule}]{tiger}|\\
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,frame={\fboxrule} {-\fboxrule}]{tiger}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Don't include the `minipage` environments, they are just to show the effect while using `\textwidth` (that's reset in a `minipage`) and not having a huge picture of the result.

[image]

Defining a command for this kind of job is quite easy:

```
\newcommand{\twincludegraphics}[2][]{%
   \includegraphics[
     width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule,
     frame={\fboxrule},
     #1]{#2}%
}
```

so you can call

```
\twincludegraphics{tiger}
```

or

```
\twincludegraphics[<other options>]{tiger}
```

where `<other options>` might even countermand the default ones for special cases.

Comment: This is very fine. Does exist a way to wrap this options in a `\newcommand` ? (since I need to use them very often)

Comment: @ital I added the new command based on the second scheme; it will be easy to change if you prefer the third one.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what you want to happen, without `adjustbox` then

```
\frame{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}}
```

will make a frame that overprints the edge of the image, so the resulting combination is still just `\textwidth` wide and will fit on the page

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}}
```

will make a border around the outside of the image so the resulting combination is too wide by the width of the padding and border on each side, so you need

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{...}}
```

So the resulting combination is `\textwidth` wide.

Or perhaps you want the image full width and the frame in the margin

```
\hspace*{\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}%
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}}%
\hspace*{\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}%
```

Comment: I want the image to be `\textwidth` wide

Comment: @ital so do you want the frame over-printing the image, or sticking in the margin? If the image is already full width there is no space for the frame down the sides

Comment: `adjustbox` sets `fboxsep` to zero when `frame` is applied I think, so you only need `\includegraphics[frame,width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule\relax]{...}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that I can deal with the frame over-printing the image