# How can I vertically align picture and text?

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to build a decent first page in a résumé but I'm struggling with the photo.

Here is what I have:

[image]

(BTW, I'm not actually going to use this picture. Not a bad idea, though.)

It kind of works but doesn't look great. I would like the text and the picture to start at the same height. The picture should be more to the right and if possible, some sort of "boxing" or frame around the picture would be quite decent...

Any ideas?

```
  \begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \section{Personal Data}
    \begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
   \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & data \\
 \textsc{Address:} & data \\
 \textsc{Phone:} & data\\
 \textsc{email:} & \href{data}{data}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{r p{11cm}}
 &\\
 &
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{/path/picture.png}
   \end{tabular}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Off-topic comment: I would not use that photograph ;-) And could you please remove that four-letter-word from your post (no, I don't mean *need* or *text*, you know which one ;-))

Comment: You can try to follow some template at [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae), avoiding a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

As @OSjerick suggested in the comments, do have a look at the [LaTeX templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae) for that sort of task.

If though you insist on 'doing things yourself', take this as a guide:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
        \section*{Personal Data}
        \begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
        \textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & data \\
        \textsc{Address:}                 & data \\
        \textsc{Phone:}                   & data\\
        \textsc{email:}                   & \href{data}{data}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/how-to-add-border-for-an-image) for how to get borders around the picture.

Note: since you did not give an MWE, I have no knowing of your used classes and packages etc - so incorporate whatever you need from my code into yours.