# Inserting boundary box around graph

Tags: graphics, border

[image]

I wish to insert a black boundary box around a graph. I have searched through the forum but I couldn't find a way to do so. The image attached is how my graph looks like.

Below is my document code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height = 3in]{/Users/kusha/Desktop/graphs/kden_2011.pdf}
\caption{Kernel density curves of male and female wages in 2011}
\label{fig:kden_2011}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/how-to-add-border-for-an-image) should help you.

Comment: I am extremely sorry to have not seen this before.

Comment: Try `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}` of `frame` package.

Comment: @Masroor Sorry for the confusion, it works now. Also, is there a way I can create a one line space between the caption and the image?

Comment: `\usepackage[skip=1.0ex]{caption}`.