# How to create a frame for tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have a figure structured as:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, matrix, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm,  
        minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB2
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB1
    },
    arrow/.style={
        blue,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    },  
    dasharrow/.style={
        blue, dashed,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    }
}

\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
    % blocks
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
        row sep=4ex,
        column sep=5.4em,
        nodes={anchor=center},
        column 2/.style={nodes={process}},
        ] (m) {
        & Text &&[-3em]\\
        |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} & Text &&\\[-2ex]
        & Text & |[startstop]| Text & |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[height=.5cm]{example-image-b} \\[7ex]
        & Text &&\\
        & Text &&\\
    };
    % block background
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [draw, fit=(m-1-2)(m-3-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
        \node [draw, fit=(m-4-2)(m-5-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
    \end{scope}    
    % vertical arrows
    \foreach[evaluate=\myblock as \mysucc using int(\myblock+1)] 
        \myblock in {1,2,...,4}
        {\draw[arrow] (m-\myblock-2) -- (m-\mysucc-2);}
    % horizontal arrows
    \coordinate (a) at ([yshift=2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (a) -- (m-2-1.east|-a) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-2-1.east|-b) -- (b) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (c) -- (m-3-3.west|-c) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (d) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-3.west|-d) -- (d) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \draw[dasharrow] ([yshift=4ex]m-3-3.east) -| (m-3-4);   
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-4) |- ([yshift=-4ex]m-3-3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

When using `\fbox{\includegraphics{}}` approach the result is as what shown in the figure:
[image]

How can I create a frame for such a figure?

Thank you

Comment: If the frame doesn't have to be Ti*k*Z, put the `tikzpicture` in a `\fbox`.

Comment: @Skillmon When I used it the whole tikz items of the picture become messy

Comment: Oh, you meant around the whole figure with `\caption` and stuff. Take a look at the `tcolorbox` package and the `mdframed` package.

Comment: I mean as what happen in the normal pictures like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/how-to-add-border-for-an-image/20715). But my image is a tiks picture not a file.

Comment: In this case, can you provide a small but complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` including all necessary packages?

Comment: As @Skillmon's first comment indicates, you can put the whole `tikzpicture` inside the `\fbox{}` command, just as you would with `\fbox{\includegraphics{}}`. Could you show us the code you used which resulted in the picture becoming messy? It would help to have an example of what you mean here.

Comment: @cfr I included the result I got when using the \fbox approach and the code is included as well, thank you.

Comment: I don't know what Ti*k*Z is doing, but apparently one cannot read this `tikzpicture` as an argument to a macro. One could use `\setbox0\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}\fbox{\unhbox0}` if `\fbox` should be used. That is really strange behaviour to me (if it is not caused by some catcode changes that is).

Comment: @Skillmon The error I get is `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options `. (I mean with `\fbox` and not your workaround, of course.)

Comment: @cfr the same as I get without the workaround -- still caused by the wrong catcode of `&`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that nobody mentioned `show background rectangle` option which I think it's the easier solution.

`Background` library is usually mentioned to draw on background layer, but it also provides `show background rectangle` which can be used to draw a frame around the `tikzpicture`. You can define a separation between borders and frame, and also the used style.

Following code shows the default solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, matrix, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm,  
        minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB2
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB1
    },
    arrow/.style={
        blue,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    },  
    dasharrow/.style={
        blue, dashed,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    }
}

\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,show background rectangle]
    % blocks
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
        row sep=4ex,
        column sep=5.4em,
        nodes={anchor=center},
        column 2/.style={nodes={process}},
        ] (m) {
        & Text &&[-3em]\\
        |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} & Text &&\\[-2ex]
        & Text & |[startstop]| Text & |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[height=.5cm]{example-image-b} \\[7ex]
        & Text &&\\
        & Text &&\\
    };
    % block background
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [draw, fit=(m-1-2)(m-3-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
        \node [draw, fit=(m-4-2)(m-5-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
    \end{scope}    
    % vertical arrows
    \foreach[evaluate=\myblock as \mysucc using int(\myblock+1)] 
        \myblock in {1,2,...,4}
        {\draw[arrow] (m-\myblock-2) -- (m-\mysucc-2);}
    % horizontal arrows
    \coordinate (a) at ([yshift=2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (a) -- (m-2-1.east|-a) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-2-1.east|-b) -- (b) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (c) -- (m-3-3.west|-c) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (d) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-3.west|-d) -- (d) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \draw[dasharrow] ([yshift=4ex]m-3-3.east) -| (m-3-4);   
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-4) |- ([yshift=-4ex]m-3-3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, is there a way to add a space only at the top an bottom of the figure, since I don't want to increase it from the left and right

Comment: @User505: Change `inner frame ysep`. See section 43 Background library in [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: Brilliant! thank you very much, the easiest and powerful solution

Answer (score 11):

Is this what you want to achieve?

The matrix is a node, you could draw its border, without adding external frames.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, matrix, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm,  
        minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB2
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB1
    },
    arrow/.style={
        blue,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    },  
    dasharrow/.style={
        blue, dashed,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    }
}

\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
        % blocks
        \matrix[matrix of nodes,
        draw, inner xsep=6pt,inner ysep=20pt,%frame 
        row sep=4ex,
        column sep=5.4em,
        nodes={anchor=center},
        column 2/.style={nodes={process}},
        ] (m) {
            & Text &&[-3.5em]\\
            |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} & Text &&\\
            & Text & |[startstop]| Text & |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[height=.5cm]{example-image-b} \\[7ex]
            & Text &&\\
            & Text &&\\
        };
        % block background
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [draw, fit=(m-1-2)(m-3-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
        \node [draw, fit=(m-4-2)(m-5-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
        \end{scope}    
        % vertical arrows
        \foreach[evaluate=\myblock as \mysucc using int(\myblock+1)] 
        \myblock in {1,2,...,4}
        {\draw[arrow] (m-\myblock-2) -- (m-\mysucc-2);}
        % horizontal arrows
        \coordinate (a) at ([yshift=2ex]m-2-2.west);
        \draw[dasharrow] (a) -- (m-2-1.east|-a) node[midway, above]{Text};
        \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-2-2.west);
        \draw[dasharrow] (m-2-1.east|-b) -- (b) node[midway, above]{Text};
        \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=2ex]m-3-2.east);
        \draw[dasharrow] (c) -- (m-3-3.west|-c) node[midway, above]{Text};
        \coordinate (d) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-3-2.east);
        \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-3.west|-d) -- (d) node[midway, above, align=center]{Texttext\\texttext};
        \draw[dasharrow] ([yshift=4ex]m-3-3.east) -| (m-3-4);   
        \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-4) |- ([yshift=-4ex]m-3-3.east); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvote all user that have given an answer. All your works are excellent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To highlight the modification made by the code you proposed is only addthis line right?`draw, inner xsep=6pt,inner ysep=20pt,%frame`

Comment: @User505 That is the main change. I have also removed the `[-2ex]` at the end of the second line of the matrix, because now the nodes have the same height and it isn't needed anymore, and I changed `[-3em]` into `[-3.5em]` to avoid the overfull hbox warning.

Answer (score 9):

A frame can also be set inside `tikzpicture` at the end, when the bounding box is known:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick, mark=*]
      (0, 0) -- (1, 2) -- (2, 0)
      (.4, .8) -- (1.6, .8)
    ;
    \fill[radius=2pt, red]
      (0, 0) circle[]
      (1, 2) circle[]
      (2, 0) circle[]
      (.4, .8) circle[]
      (1.6, .8) circle[]
      (.9, .8) pic[scale=.1]{duck}
      (.9, 0) pic[xscale=-.1, yscale=.1, /duck/water]{duck}
    ;

    % Frame
    \def\sep{\fboxsep}
    \draw[thick, blue!75!black, double=yellow]
      (current bounding box.south west) ++(-\sep, -\sep) coordinate (ll)
      (current bounding box.north east) ++(\sep, \sep) coordinate (ur)
      (ll) rectangle (ur)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

Just for the sake of it, here a version which uses `\fbox` and the `\scantokens` macro to make it work in `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, matrix, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm,  
        minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB2
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB1
    },
    arrow/.style={
        blue,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    },  
    dasharrow/.style={
        blue, dashed,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    }
}

\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\newcommand\stupidfbox[1]
  {%
    \fbox{\scantokens{#1\ignorespaces}}%
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
\stupidfbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
    % blocks
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
        row sep=4ex,
        column sep=5.4em,
        nodes={anchor=center},
        column 2/.style={nodes={process}},
        ] (m) {
        & Text &&[-3em]\\
        |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} & Text &&\\[-2ex]
        & Text & |[startstop]| Text & |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[height=.5cm]{example-image-b} \\[7ex]
        & Text &&\\
        & Text &&\\
    };
    % block background
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [draw, fit=(m-1-2)(m-3-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
        \node [draw, fit=(m-4-2)(m-5-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
    \end{scope}    
    % vertical arrows
    \foreach[evaluate=\myblock as \mysucc using int(\myblock+1)] 
        \myblock in {1,2,...,4}
        {\draw[arrow] (m-\myblock-2) -- (m-\mysucc-2);}
    % horizontal arrows
    \coordinate (a) at ([yshift=2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (a) -- (m-2-1.east|-a) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-2-1.east|-b) -- (b) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (c) -- (m-3-3.west|-c) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (d) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-3.west|-d) -- (d) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \draw[dasharrow] ([yshift=4ex]m-3-3.east) -| (m-3-4);   
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-4) |- ([yshift=-4ex]m-3-3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Though I already gave an answer this one is different from that one. The `\matrix` in a `tikzpicture` does use ampersands of a different catcode. As a result, it can't be used in an argument as the catcode change is lost because they are already tokenized. There is however the option `ampersand replacement`. If that is used one can use the result in an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, matrix, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm,  
        minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB2
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB1
    },
    arrow/.style={
        blue,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    },  
    dasharrow/.style={
        blue, dashed,-{Stealth[length=6pt]}
    }
}

\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
  \fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,ampersand replacement=\&]
    % blocks
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,
        row sep=4ex,
        column sep=5.4em,
        nodes={anchor=center},
        column 2/.style={nodes={process}},
        ] (m) {
        \& Text \&\&[-3em]\\
        |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} \& Text \&\&\\[-2ex]
        \& Text \& |[startstop]| Text \& |[inner sep=0pt]|\includegraphics[height=.5cm]{example-image-b} \\[7ex]
        \& Text \&\&\\
        \& Text \&\&\\
    };
    % block background
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node [draw, fit=(m-1-2)(m-3-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
        \node [draw, fit=(m-4-2)(m-5-2), fill=cyan!5, inner sep=10pt] {};
    \end{scope}    
    % vertical arrows
    \foreach[evaluate=\myblock as \mysucc using int(\myblock+1)] 
        \myblock in {1,2,...,4}
        {\draw[arrow] (m-\myblock-2) -- (m-\mysucc-2);}
    % horizontal arrows
    \coordinate (a) at ([yshift=2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (a) -- (m-2-1.east|-a) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-2-2.west);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-2-1.east|-b) -- (b) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (c) -- (m-3-3.west|-c) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \coordinate (d) at ([yshift=-2ex]m-3-2.east);
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-3.west|-d) -- (d) node[midway, above]{Text};
    \draw[dasharrow] ([yshift=4ex]m-3-3.east) -| (m-3-4);   
    \draw[dasharrow] (m-3-4) |- ([yshift=-4ex]m-3-3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have two questions, how can I edit the size of the space between the border and the image itself in case I want ti increase it. The second is how can I make the figure in the center and not goes to the right of the image. Thank you

Comment: For the space: `\fboxsep=3em` (or what ever you want). The image should always be in centre of the `\fbox`. For the horizontal alignment add a `\makebox[\linewidth]{...}` around the `\fbox` command. @User505

Comment: Sorry for bothering but this will increase the size around the whole figure, what if I want to increase it only at the top and bottom of the figure?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

it seems that `matrix` in `tikzpicture` somehow interact with `\fbox`. if you rewrite your flowchart as is done in mwe below, than `\fbox` works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning
                }
\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=RYB2,
        minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.5cm, align=center
                    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle, draw, fill=RYB1,
        minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center
                    },
    arrow/.style={
        blue,-{Stealth[length=6pt]},
                }
        }% end of tikzset
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 16mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   FIT/.style = {draw, fill=cyan!5, inner sep=8pt},
process/.append style = {on chain=A, join=by arrow},
         font = \small
                        ]
    % blocks
\node[process] {Text};              % A-1
\node[process] {Text};              %
\node[process] {Text};              % A-3
%
\node[process,below=8mm of A-3] {Text}; % A-4
\node[process] {Text};                  % A-5
%
\node (n1) [inner sep=0pt, left=of A-2] {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}};
\node (n2) [startstop,right=of A-3]     {Text};
\node (n3) [inner sep=0pt,right=4mm of n2] {\includegraphics[height=.5cm]{example-image-b}};
    % block background
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node [FIT, fit=(A-1)(A-3)] {};
\node [FIT, fit=(A-4)(A-5)] {};
    \end{scope}
    % horizontal arrows
    \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={arrow, densely dashed}]
\coordinate[above=3mm of A-2.west] (a1);
\coordinate[below=3mm of A-2.west] (a2);
    \draw (a1) -- node[above] {Text} (a1-| n1.east);
    \draw (a2 -| n1.east) -- node[above] {Text} (a2);
%
\coordinate[above=3mm of A-3.east] (b1);
\coordinate[below=3mm of A-3.east] (b2);
    \draw (b1) -- node[above] {Text} (b1 -| n2.west);
    \draw (b2 -| n2.west) -- node[above] {Text} (b2);
%
\coordinate[above=6mm of n2.east] (c1);
\coordinate[below=6mm of n2.east] (c2);
    \draw (c1) -| (n3);
    \draw (c2) -| (n3);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: See my new answer for a short explanation why `\matrix` doesn't work in `\fbox`.

Comment: @Skillmon, i suspect that faoult is in use of ampersands ... but for fun and exercise i rather rewrote flowchart code than try to investigate this. +1 for your answer! :-)