# Border around any general figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, border

Is there is any **general command** to put a border around any "figure" (pictures, tables, tikz diagrams). In my case I have a document which uses some images and diagrams made using the `circuitikz` package. I would like to enclose both of them in borders. I have referred to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/how-to-add-border-for-an-image) post which mentions `\frame{\includegraphics{image}}` but this seems to work only for image files. I was looking for something more general which can be applied to *anything* that can be considered a figure ie anything that can wrapped in an environment (`figure`, `table`, `circuitiz`, etc). Does such a thing exist ? And if it does, would it be possible to control the thickness of the border ?

Comment: I think `fbox` is what you are looking for, altough I don't know if you can control its margin. Also, you will need to wrap each environment individually, as far as I know

Comment: with `tcolorbox` you can include into a colored box whatever you want. you can decide background color, frame color and width, margins between borders and contents, ...

Comment: There is no reason why frame should work only with includegraphics.

Comment: `\frame` will frame anything, try `\frame{hello}`

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, will try out all and try to post the one I think works the best.

Comment: You can use `\restylefloat` (float package) to convert figures and/or tables to `boxed` style.